Is this a valid formal proof?
Coming from learning rules of inference, I wanted to try a formal proof to see how this topic relates to proofs and to understand more deeply.
By looking at some examples of proofs (especially conditional ones), I noticed that most are informal (they have steps the reader can fill in).
As I progressed in the direct formal proof, I realized it’s not very practical, and it’s better to apply algebra; by this, I mean applying the properties directly instead of working in the form of predicates, quantifiers, and inference rules (modus ponens, etc.), which is equivalent and could be seen as missing steps (part of an informal proof).
So, I concluded that by “applying algebraic properties,” we’re applying inference rules (like modus ponens) but skipping some steps (informal). The axiom of equality substitution (deductive system) lets us combine various axioms or use them together. This makes more sense to me since there’s no need to express quantifiers in theorems or informal proofs. Instantiation seems to use the formula informally.
I can see that the rest of the formal proof would mainly involve substitutions using axioms and definitions, but I still don’t see how these are equivalent (having a bunch of equalities if we did the proof informally with "algebra") to:
$mn = s^2t^2 = (ss)(tt)= (st)(st)= (st) ^ 2$
So far, the equal sign in the informal context seems to indicate that some substitution or deduction was applied(though I could be very wrong).
Question:
Can anyone explain why applying a bunch of inference rules formally is the same as having a sequence of equalities in the informal proof, specifically the equality ?
For instance, in this proof, the goal was to reach $a ^2 b ^ 2= d$. In the informal, it’s just $mn = a ^ 2 b ^ 2$.
And in proofs, especially of the form $P \Rightarrow Q$, we cannot use the conclusion in the proof, so could the step of doing m* n = ...  can be justified by the axiom of closure for multiplication ?
Because it’s the beginning of the proof, and we’re only given(assume) that m and n are squares, so to reach their product, we use the axiom. I’m just trying to understand the justification for starting there.
Formal Proof:
Theorem
If $m$ and $n$ are both perfect squares, then $mn$ is also a perfect square.
Predicates

$P(n , b)$ = " $n = b ^ 2$"
$R(m , n , c)$ = " $mn = c ^ 2$"
$S(m , n)$ = "$m \cdot n = n \cdot  m$"
$W(m , n)$ = "$m ^2 \cdot n ^2 = (mn) ^ 2$"
$T(m)$ : "$m ^ 2 = m \cdot m$"
$V(m , n , p)$ : "$(m \cdot n) \cdot p = m \cdot (n \cdot p)$"
$K(m , n , p)$ : "$m \cdot n = p$"
$L(a , b)$ : "a = b"

Axioms

$\forall m \forall n S(m, n)$
$\forall m \forall n \forall p V(m ,n ,p )$
$\forall m \forall n \exists p K(m, n , p)$ Closure Law of multiplication
$\forall a \forall b \forall \phi$ H(a , b , $\phi$)
$\forall a \forall b  ((L(a,b) \wedge  \phi(a)) \rightarrow \phi(b))$ Equality Substitution Axiom

Definition

$\forall  m  \exists a P(m , a)$
$\forall m T(m)$

Direct Formal Proof of:
$$\forall m \forall a P(m, a) \wedge \forall n \forall bP(n, b) \Rightarrow  \exists c R(m, n, c)$$



Number
Premise
Reason




1
$$\forall m \forall n P(m, n) \wedge \forall m \forall n P(m , n)$$
Premise


2
$$P(m, a) \wedge P(n , b)$$
Universal Instantiation


3
$$\forall m \forall n S(m, n)$$
Premise


4
$$S(m, n)$$
Universal Instantiation


5
$$\forall m T(m)$$
Premise


6
$$T(m)$$
Universal Instantiation


7
$$T(n)$$
Universal Instantiation *S


8
$$\forall m \forall n \exists p K(m, n , p)$$
Premise


9
$$K(m , n , p)$$
Universal Instantiation


10
$$\forall a \forall b ((L(a,b) \wedge \phi(a)) \rightarrow \phi(b))$$
Premise


11
$$(L(m,a ^ 2) \wedge K(m, n, p)) \rightarrow K(a ^ 2 , n, p)$$
Universal Instantiation (10)


12
$$P(m, a ^ 2)$$
Simplification (2)


13
$$K(a ^ 2 , n , p)$$
Modus Ponens (11) (12)


14
$$P(m, b ^ 2)$$
Simplification (2)


15
$$(L(n,b ^ 2) \wedge K(a ^ 2, n, p)) \rightarrow K(a ^ 2 , b ^ 2, p)$$
Universal Instantiation (10)


16
$$K(a ^ 2 , b ^ 2 , p)$$
Modus Ponens (14) (15)



Reached until:
$a ^ 2 b ^ 2 = d$

That is the wrong proof.$~$You want to prove that, for every $m$ and $n$, if they are both perfect squares, then their product is a perfect square.$$\vdash\forall m,\forall n,\bigl(((\exists a,\mathrm P(m,a))\wedge(\exists b,\mathrm P(n,b)))\to(\exists c,\mathrm R(m,n,c))\bigr)$$

PS: Your "definition" of $\forall m\exists a~\mathrm P(m,a)$ states: "Everything is a perfect square."   Are you sure you want to declare that?

Rather: $\forall m,\forall a~(\mathrm P(m,a)\leftrightarrow\mathrm L(m,a^2))$ is definitional, as are $\forall m,\forall n,\forall p~(\mathrm R(m,n.p)\leftrightarrow\mathrm K(m,n,p^2))$ and $\forall m~(\mathrm T(m)\leftrightarrow\mathrm K(m,m,m^2))$ and so on for $\rm S, V, $ and $\rm W$.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
You seek to show that, for any two variables, if they are both perfect squares, then their product is a perfect square.
Your domain needs: two axioms for $L$-quality (substitutability*, and reflexivity), three axioms for "product of two variables" (continuity, commutativity, and associativity), one definition for "square of a variable", and one definition for "is a perfect square" ($P$).
[Note: this does not actually define what a "product" is, just lists three of its properties, and since "square" and "perfect square" are herein defined in terms of product, they are not fully defined here either.]
(* An axiom schema, to be precise.)
$\qquad\fitch{~~1.~~\forall x~\forall y~(L(x,y)\to(\phi(x)\to\phi(y))\\~~2.~~\forall x~L(x,x)
\\~~3.~~\forall x\,\forall y\,\exists p~L(x\cdot y,p)\\~~4.~~\forall x\forall y~L(x\cdot y,y\cdot x)\\~~5.~~\forall x\forall y\forall x~L(x\cdot (y\cdot z),(x\cdot y)\cdot z)\\~~6.~~\forall x~L(x^2,x\cdot x)\\~~7.~~\forall x~(P(x)\leftrightarrow \exists y~L(x,y^2))}{~~~~\vdots\\~~~~.~~\forall m~\forall n~(P(m)\land P(n))\to P(m\cdot n))}$
